# Swift 3 - How to obtain error origin information?

Tags: swift3

Upon my application crashing, I would like to obtain information regarding the origin of where the error occurred. Ideally what I'm trying to do is something like the following:

```
do {
    try obj.thatThrowsError()
} catch {
    print("Error on: line \(error.lineNumber)")
    print("Col \(error.column)")
    print("In file: \(error.sourceFileName)")
    print(error.message)
}
```

I realize that this information isn't available by default. What I have is something like:

```
struct CustomError: Error {
    let lineNumber: Int 
    // other vars here
}
```

And then using it like:

```
let error = CustomError(/* initializes vars here */)
```

But that's a lot of manual work and if the line changes then that will require manual changes. Is there a way to do this but scrape this data more dynamically?

Comment: You can get the line number and other things dynamically by using `#file`, `#column`, `#line`, and `#function`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io), which provides nice [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics), which says lots of information about your crash including, which line(line number), which device (iphone 5, iphone 6s),how many users got the crash from each device, which time,  and many more with anlytics with nice UI. This is completely **Free** and can use for both **iOS** and **Android.**